# FPDF Header looks different across PDF pages?

Tags: php, php-7, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create a PDF report based on data from MySQL. But I'm having a styling issue with my header.

The first page header looks like this:

[image: First Header]

but each page after that looks like this:

[image: Second Page Beyond Header]

Here is my full code for the report:

```
<?php

require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
//$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=ccrp_db', 'root', '');
include("../dbconnect.php");

class Report extends FPDF {
    function header() {
        $this->Image('logo.png', 10, 6, 25, 25);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
        $this->Cell(200, 5, 'Cabarrus County GOP Convention' . ' ' . date("Y"), 0, 0, 'C');
        $this->Ln();
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
        $this->Cell(200, 10, 'Attendance Report', 0, 0, 'C');
        $this->Ln(25);
    }

    function footer() {
        $this->SetY(-15);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        $this->Cell(0, 10, 'Page '. $this->PageNo(), 0, 0,'R');
    }

    function headerSummary() {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(275, 5, 'Summary', 0, 0, 'L');
        $this->Ln(10);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
        $this->SetLeftMargin(50);
        $this->Cell(20, 10, 'Precinct', 1, 0, 'C');
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Delegates Present', 1, 0, 'C');
        $this->Cell(40, 10, 'Delegates Absent', 1, 0, 'C');
        $this->Cell(20, 10, 'Total', 1, 0, 'C');
        $this->Ln();

    }

    function viewSummary() {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
        global $pdo;
        $sql = "SELECT IFNULL(m.precinct, 'Totals') as 'precinct', COUNT(at.member_id) as 'delegates_present', COUNT(ab.member_id) as 'delegates_absent', COUNT(at.member_id) + COUNT(ab.member_id) as 'total' FROM members m LEFT JOIN attendance as at ON at.member_id = m.id LEFT JOIN absence as ab ON ab.member_id = m.id GROUP BY m.precinct WITH ROLLUP;";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            $this->Cell(20, 10, $data->precinct, 1, 0, 'C');
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->delegates_present, 1, 0, 'C');
            $this->Cell(40, 10, $data->delegates_absent, 1, 0, 'C');
            $this->Cell(20, 10, $data->total, 1, 0, 'C');
            $this->Ln();
        }
    }
}

$pdf = new Report();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage('P', 'Letter', 0);
$pdf->headerSummary();
$pdf->viewSummary();
$pdf->Output();

?>
```

How can I make the header look the same across all of the pages? I'm not sure what I did wrong...

Comment: The only thing that really stands out would be `$this->SetLeftMargin(50);`

Comment: Hmm... I commented out the line and it worked, but the table is now aligned to the left of the page. How do I align it to the center?

Comment: Since margins are intended to be uniform throughout the document, I recommend using `$this->SetX(50)` instead of margin. This way you can reset the X position as needed. `$x = $this->GetX(); $this->SetX(50); //.... $this->Ln(); $this->SetX($x);`

Comment: That appeared to do the trick! Although I'm having an issue with the SQL statement inside the table. Apparently, the absences column is not grabbing any data and it should have a 1 in the 10-00 row? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dc7e07/2/0

Comment: You should ask a separate question regarding the SQL troubleshooting, since it is effectively a separate issue than the one you were having with the alignment of your PDF.